# Customer Ratings on Apple Appstore?

Tags: iphone, upload, download, app-store, rating

I don't know whats wrong with Apple Customer Ratings system on Appstore.

Recently I have uploaded two apps on appstore. And still there are no ratings/reviews on apps. Infact I observed there are 1000s of downloads has been made in last 2 days.

To verify this 1 of my friend also added his comment with rating yesterday on 1 of my App. But his comment also not visible, still there are zero customer reviews in both Apps.

Can anyone update me regarding this issue ?

Comment: Are you checking the correct country?

Comment: That application has been uploaded Worldwide. I am just checking it by going through Appstore or itunes. It shouldn't be country biased ?

Comment: Just wondering if you are checking the reviews in the country that the review got posted. They sometimes need some time to show up (and some might get rejected for obvious reasons).

Comment: use a service like appfigures to check your ratings and comments in all appstores worldwide

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my past experience, it takes a day or two for Apple to review comments for songs and apps in iTunes and the App Store. Apple must review them to make sure they are appropriate and meet guidelines, at which point they will be posted. Best thing to do: Just be patient. If nothing shows after a few days, then I would contact Apple. Best of Luck!

Comment: I think i have to wait 1-2 more days :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It takes a couple of days for the reviews to show up since I believe Apple checks the comments for spam or offensive materials. That is just my speculation. But you should check iTunes Connect for customer reviews since checking the reviews on your computer or iOS device only shows the reviews for your country. To check in iTunes Connect reviews click your app, go into view details of that app and then click customer reviews. There you can check the reviews of all the countries. I have found that instead of doing that you can go to this site http://www.appergy.com/apps/Search-iPhone-iPad-iPod-Touch-Apps.aspx. It goes through all the countries and shows you the reviews.

Comment: Appergy appears to be dead as of 2022

Answer (score 1):

There are problems from time to time with this in the Appstore, sometimes comments take several days to show up:

[App store review not showing](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/business-legal-app-store/18612-app-store-reviews-not-showing-up.html)

Comment: Never show at All ? :O If this is the issue then its a huge problem

Comment: Well actually I think the never show at all is an exaggeration =D, edited my post.